# FORTRAN - MAXLOC which returns all positions of maximum values in array?

Tags: arrays, fortran

I am looking for a way to get all positions with the maximum value for an array and not just the first. As far as I understand MAXLOC will only return the first it finds. Is there a way to get all?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

[To extend the answer by @HighPerformanceMark to your array of rank 2.]

The shapes of the two arrays in `PACK` (the indices and the mask) must match (except when the mask is a scalar - the term is *conformable*).  As your mask `matrix==MAXVAL(matrix)` isn't scalar you can reshape the element selection array to be conformable:

```
PACK(RESHAPE([(ix, ix=1, SIZE(matrix))], SHAPE(matrix)), matrix==MAXVAL(matrix))
```

to give you the elements in array element order (that is, a single integer representing it as though there were a rank-1 array).  This is essentially the same as the previous answer, but you then need to map array element order to your various dimensions.  This mapping is trivial in the rank-1 case.  [In general, if lower bounds are not 1 for some rank then you will also need to take that into account.]

Alternatively, you could loop over the various rows/columns of matrix and use the rank-1 slice approach individually.

Even, as @HighPerformanceMark further commented, when one has a higher rank array this array element order result is less intuitive and perhaps more tricky to handle.  Unless the multi-rank indices are persistently useful one may be better off with a clearer looping approach:

```
do i2=1, SIZE(matrix,2)
  do i1=1, SIZE(matrix,1)
    if (matrix(i1,i2).ne.MAXVAL(matrix)) cycle
    ...
  end do
end do
```

Comment: The problem with this approach was that it put the indexes for x and y into one integer. Like so:
3753        3809        3921       31713       31769       31881       44761       44817       44929
Where the first one would be 37, 53. This is easy for the first few but once I get higher in the index numbers I don't know whether it is 31, 881 or 318, 81. Maybe this has something to do with the way I am printing the values? I just use "WRITE(*,*)"

Comment: I should perhaps have been clearer with the result you get.  You aren't seeing (37, 53), for example, but it's element 3753 in order of memory storage.  If `matrix` is 75x75, say, then your indices will be (3,51).

Answer (score 2):

Try something like

```
pack([(ix,ix=1,size(array))],array==maxval(array))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the compiler is complaining about "Incompatible ranks in arguments 'array' and 'mask' for intrinsic 'pack' (1 and 2) at (1)"

Comment: Well, without sight of your code I'd just be taking stabs in the dark. I'd probably stab myself in the foot.

Comment: INTEGER, DIMENSION(233, 233)  :: matrix
INTEGER     :: i
OPEN(UNIT=4, file='test.txt', STATUS='unknown')

! matrix is an array containing scoring values between -20 and +7, too complex and irrelevant to post here

WRITE(4,*) pack([(i,i=1,size(matrix))],matrix==maxval(matrix))

Comment: Ahh, you have a rank 2 array.  My solution, based on a false assumption, probably isn't much help to you.

Comment: At some point clever tricks, such as using `pack` and `reshape`, become more difficult to code and to understand and you're better off just writing a loop or two.