# Finding multiple local maximums within a multidimensional fortran array using maxloc and maxval

Tags: multidimensional-array, fortran, max

I am working with a large computational fluid dynamics (finite difference) code which simulates forming solar systems. It is written in fortran and uses a 3D cylindrical grid to flux conserved quantities (mass, momentum, ...). I did not write the code, but use it to perform research. I am currently performing data analysis on output files, and I am  having some trouble finding multiple local maximums in a 3D density array.

I first tried to use the basic maxloc and maxval intrinsic functions:

```
print*, maxloc(array)
print*, maxval(array)
```

This only provided me with the value of the first maximum encountered. I am looking for over-densities within the array that could be the precursors to forming planetesimals. I need to find them all, their locations, and then perform more analysis to find their "edge" within the grid, and integrate to find the total mass in each over-dense region. First things first, though. I need to find all the local maxima.

I found these two discussions, but neither seemed to solve the problem:
1) [FORTRAN - MAXLOC which returns all positions of maximum values in array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21985356/fortran-maxloc-which-returns-all-positions-of-maximum-values-in-array)
2) [Finding [index of] the minimal value in array which satisfies a condition in Fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20649128/finding-index-of-the-minimal-value-in-array-which-satisfies-a-condition-in-for?rq=1)

Using information in the first discussion, I tried to write my own multiple maxima finder, but only managed to do what the intrinsic functions do.

```
temp=0.0
do L = 0, LMAX-1
 do K = 0, KMAX-1
  do J = 0, JMAX-1
   if (array(j,k,l)>=temp) then
    temp = array(j,k,l)
    tempj = j
    tempk = k
    templ = l
   end if
  end do
 end do
end do
```

I also tried:

```
temp(j,k,l)=0.0
do L = 0, LMAX-1
 do K = 0, KMAX-1
  do J = 0, JMAX-1
   if (array(j,k,l).gt.maxval(array)) then
    temp(j,k,l) = array(j,k,l)
    print*, temp(j,k,l), j,k,l
   else 
    go to 20
   end if
  end do
 end do
end do
20 continue
```

hoping it would skip the first maxima, and go on to the next. This did not work either, but I now see the flaw in my logic. I am now thinking that I can use maxloc(array) to find the j,k,l location of the first maxima, then write a loop which begins at that j,k,l index to find the next maxima, and continue in this way until I've found them all. I think this brute force method should work, but it seems clunky and computationally wasteful.

I am a physicist before I am a programmer. I was just hoping that someone could point me to a more elegant way of doing this. It seems really simple, so I am wondering why there is no intrinsic function which can already do this.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I wouldn't use maxval at all. Just use a basic do loop.

Comment: Can you explain why http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21985356/fortran-maxloc-which-returns-all-positions-of-maximum-values-in-array does not help?

Comment: Ok, so how do you define a local maximum? Any element which has neighbouring elements smaller, or smaller or equal,  value than its own value?

Comment: Forget the code at first. How would *you* pick these points yourself? I don't think you know that yet.

Comment: Using a mask with MAXVAL/MAXLOC works. As @Ross pointed out... What do you mean by a local minima? If you have a 2D manifold, then you can envision putting it in a box and overfilling it with water... Then when you see a mountain sticking out of the ocean you have a maxima. At some point you have another visual peak. You either need a gradient/curl or some other method to ignore (using a mask) the sides of the mountains and only get the peaks. Beyond 2D I have no analogy that can help. I called the routine "Toes" because it was a toe curler to work out at first.

Comment: Hint: if you're looking for the local maxima of some function φ(x,y,z), you're probably looking for where ∇φ→0 while ∇²φ>0. You can use a finite-difference approximation to calculate ∇φ and ∇²φ.

Comment: Just do a local check as to whether the local value is greater than its neighbours e.g. `if(all(array(jlo:jup,klo:kup,llo:lup) <= array(j,k,l))) then...` where `jlo=max(0,j-1), jup=min(jmax-1,j+1)` etc. Save the local maxima locations in some integer arrays and you can skip through the 3D array using indirect adressing.

Comment: @VladimirF, yes it is about local maxima of different values. The previous answer suggested pack and reshape, but indexing became very problematic and did not appear to be doing what I need.

Comment: @Ross. Yes, I did not mention that I already have a code which will integrate in the z direction to create a 2D surface. From this I can visually look at a plot and see that I have five overdense regions in my grid.

Comment: @Jabirali. Thank you, I think this might work. I will let you know if it does.